# initiating sequelizer mysql connection via tunnel-ssh module

Tags: mysql, node.js, ssh

I'd like to connect to a MySQL database using Sequelizer. Right now, I'm getting a Connection Refused Error.

To access the database, I have to SSH in. According to Mick Hansen here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3753, one way to SSH in is to use tunnel-ssh to establish the tunnel, then initiate Sequelizer.

My (unsuccessful) approach so far has been to initiate the tunnel, then when the tunnel opens, test whether Sequelizer has authenticated.

**Update**

- Host: DigitalOcean
- CLI Success: I can 1) ssh into digitalocean server 2) login into mysql from the server and 3) access all database information as the root user.
- Sequel Pro: I can also log into the database using Sequel Pro.
- MySQL 127.0.0.1:3306: Based on the mysql/my.cnf file, the port is 3306 and the bind-address is 127.0.0.1. The config file also says instead of skip-networking, the default is to listen only on localhost, if that's relevant.
- socketPath -> Error Connection Switching from TCP to socket seems to sometimes work for this type of problem, but when I tried it, I continued to get a connection refused error.
- 2 Error Types - *"All Configured Authentication Methods Failed"* and *"Error Connection Refused"*

Thanks for the help!

Code:

```
// sequelize config
 var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'user', 'pass', {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  dialect: 'mysql',
  port: 3306,

  pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idle: 20000
  }
});

// tunnel config
var config = {
      user:'user',
      host:'sshHost',
      port:22,
      dstHost:'127.0.0.1',
      dstPort:3306,
      srcHost:'127.0.0.1',
      srcPort:3306,
      localHost:'127.0.0.1',
      localPort: 3306,
      privateKey:require('fs').readFileSync('/path/to/key')
    };

var tunnel = require('tunnel-ssh');

// initiate tunnel
tunnel(config, function (error, server) {
  //....
  if(error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    console.log('server:', server);

  // test sequelize connection
    sequelize
        .authenticate()
        .then(function(err) {
            console.log('Connection established');
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.error('unable to establish connection', err);
        })
  }
})
```

When my config is set to the object above, I get an **"All configuration methods failed error"**.

If I change my config to the below, I get a **"Sequelize Error Connection Refused"** error.

```
// tunnel config
    var config = {
          user:'user',
          host:'sshHost',
          port:22,
          dstHost:'127.0.0.1',
          dstPort:3306,
          //srcHost:'127.0.0.1',
          //srcPort:3306,
          //localHost:'127.0.0.1',
          //localPort: 3306,
          privateKey:require('fs').readFileSync('/path/to/key')
        };
```

Comment: can you show us the sequelize init bit of your code?

Comment: thanks @code-jaff, added the sequelize init bit to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

`localPort` is the port listening on your local system. Currently you have it defined as 27000 but your Sequelize config is set to 3306.

Comment: thanks mscdex. when I change the sequelizer port to 27000, or when I change the config.localPort to 3306, I get the error that the privateKey is not a valid value. Specifically: _ssh2/lib/client.js:226_
      **throw new Error('privateKey value does not contain a (valid) private key**

Comment: Did you check that private key file to ensure it's a valid, PEM-formatted private SSH key?

Comment: That may be my error. I use the private key mentioned to log into my database via Sequel Pro. With Sequel Pro, I can successfully log in. _Is it possible there's a difference between the format of the ssh key for Sequel Pro and the format that sequelize requires?_ Thanks again.

Comment: What are the first and last lines in the file at `/path/to/key` (they should be headers)?

Comment: _the first line:_ ssh-rsa _the last line:_ == jason@domain.com

Comment: also, have belatedly realized you're the author / maintainer of ssh2. thank you for that.

Comment: Ok so it looks like you're passing the path to a *public* key and not a *private* key. You need the latter. It should begin with a line that says something like "-----BEGIN xxxx PRIVATE KEY-----".